# Is it a good idea to force garbage collection in node

Tags: node.js, memory

I know that you can expose the garbage collector in node. I am just curious if this is a good idea outside of the context of testing.

Comment: In most environments, it's usually a bad idea to force GC outside of some very specific scenarios.

Comment: Why do you think you might want to do that?